# How to lookup values from dropdown lists in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, lookup, dropdownlist

I have a complicated Excel worksheet, but I will simplify what I need in a simple scenario.

I have the following sheet as raw data.

[image]

Also, I have another sheet where I can select the student's name from a list, lookup for the scores automatically, and calculate their percentage.

[image]

Now, I have a third sheet where I want to fill the percentages automatically from the second sheet.

[image]

I tried using the FILTER function but it fills the column for the selected student only.

[image]

I know there are easier solutions for this scenario, but my actual worksheet is much more complicated than this. I need to fill a column regardless of the selected value.

Comment: It seems like maybe you’re trying to reference the wrong sheet. Sheet2 is setup to show results for only 1 student at a time. Sheet3 is trying to summarize ALL students, so it should be referencing the complete data table on Sheet1 again.

Comment: Are you looking for the Dependent Drop Down List? https://trumpexcel.com/dependent-drop-down-list-in-excel/

Comment: Thanks for your useful comments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Data Table as shown below.
`Data Tab` > `What-if-Analysis` > `Data Table`
If your Data Table is in another sheet than your calculations you must make reference to column input cell in the sheet where you have your Data Table.
I mean, you must use as the Column input cell some cell from the same sheet.
[image: Data Table]

Comment: Thank you very much. Do data tables work with formatted tables? I find data tables inactive when I try to use them with formatted tables.

Comment: I don't know exactly what you mean. Data which are used in calculations may be taken from a formatted table, but results of a Data Table are a bit similar to a multi-cell array formula. And you cannot put such a formula into formatted table, because here in each cell must be a separate formula or a constant value.

Comment: Thank you very much @MGonet. The problem has been resolved using your answer.